# Jquery Doom for me - val working, focus not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-events

I have a `div` which is *popedUp* on `a` click.My problem is extremely weird, check this snippet below :

**HTML**

```
<a class="button highlightPopup" href="#adc" onclick="showPopup('popDiv');">Some Text</a>

<!-- pop up div basic markup -->
<div id="popDiv">
   <!-- lots of CSS and div here in between -->
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 1" id="cr_num1" onfocusout="validate()">
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 2" id="cr_num2" onfocusout="validate()">
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 3" id="cr_num3" onfocusout="validate()">
</div>
```

**JQ**

```
 $('a.highlightPopup').on('click', function(){
    if($('#popDiv').is(':visible')){
        console.log("ye");
        //this works            
        $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').val('test');
        //below 2 don't :(
        $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').trigger('click');
        $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').focus();
    }else{
       console.log("ney");
    }
}
```

`popDiv` is a simple div containing lot of input fields and i want to set an autofocus on first `input` when its *popedup* for validation purpose.Pretty basic stuff...right?

**Problem :**

I added `val('test')` just to see if this are working fine or not, so i have got `test` set on my div but `tigger('click')` or even `focus()` is not working.

Popup coming up is not a jquery pop but a customized div coming as an overlay.

Any ideas anyone why this is occurring???

Comment: if that code is all you actually have, where is the code that actually shows the div first? only after div is visible, can you do other finds and filters on its children.

Comment: Some related `html` and `css`-if any, would help much more to understand..

Comment: @Shaunak : exactly my point, parent become visible then only child activities happen.But not all are happening, thats the issue!

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle to demo your problem? It will be lot easier to fix it then.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ufwg2cLy/1/   it is working in the demo.can you please check this

Comment: @RamasamyKanna : yes, in ideal situation it does work.I familiar with jquery too, i suspect issue is related to showing a pop up here!!

Comment: @Shaunak : can't show pop in fiddle mate....

Comment: can you try to modify this or something along this lines to recreate the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/3kgbG/

Comment: @Shaunak : its with modal window...mine is with core div with overlay effects....m i making sense,?? sorry if m not

Comment: yes, i think i understand it better now. Correct me if I am wrong but, you div is already in the dom. just hidden. When you click the button, you want it to show, and then make some modifications on it. However you click function is just checking if it's visible.  `is(':visible')` is just going to check if it is visible, and not actually going to make it visible. You will have to do something to the effect it `.show()` on it first, and then execute the code within your `if`.. you don't even need a `if` at this point now.  `is(':visible')` will only check if div is actually visible

Comment: @Shaunak : yup...right!! `window.setTimeout` seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did some more googling and found `setTimeout` is the saviour here :

```
$('a.highlightPopup').on('click', function(){
     window.setTimeout(function(){$('#first_input_id:visible').get(0).focus();}, 100);
});
```

If anyone can, please help understand why this worked!! :\

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look below snippet demo i hope it help to you! any further help let me know. Once focusout from Input your validator function call it.

Thanks!

```js
/*$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.highlightPopup').on('click', function(){
        $('#popDiv').show();
        if($('#popDiv').is(':visible')){
       $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').focus();
     } else {
        console.log("ney");
     }
 });
});*/


function showPopup(divId) {
  $('#'+divId).show();
  if($('#popDiv').is(':visible')){
    $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').focus();
  } else {
    console.log("ney");
  }
}

function validate() {
   if ( $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').val() == '') {
     alert('Please enter first input value!');
     return false;
     
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button highlightPopup" href="#adc" onclick="showPopup('popDiv');">Some Text</a>
<div id="popDiv" style="display:none;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 1" id="cr_num1" onfocusout="validate();">
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 2" id="cr_num2" onfocusout="validate();">
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputMedium iconImg" placeholder="input 3" id="cr_num3" onfocusout="validate();">
</div>
```

Comment: u added `$('#popDiv').show();` ? Works on DOM but not with PopUp...man, m hating my design team!!!

Comment: Your looking like #popDiv open by clicking on showPopup function ?

Comment: Now i've updated snippet demo based on clicking showPopup please check it

Answer (score 1):

Filter may return multiple rows. You have to specify correct element by using index.
Try following instead:

```
$('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first')[0].trigger('click');
        $('#popDiv').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first')[0].focus();
```